# 'request' : Error: { Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to fetch some information from below mentioned API and I'm getting below error

```
const request = require('request');


var options = {
    url : 'https://example.com',
}
```

OR

```
var options = {
  url : 'https://example.com',
  agentOptions: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem')
  }
}

console.log(options)

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  console.log('body:', body ); 
});



  error: { Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
        at Error (native)
        at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
        at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
        at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38) code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' }
```

sample pem file

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**I don't want to use either NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' or  rejectUnauthorized: false**

Comment: then you have to use a trusted certificate...

Comment: the options that you don't want to use, they are your solution or you have to use a trusted certificate as @RidgeA said

Comment: how would I know whether certificate is trusted one or not

Comment: I want to use trusted certificate-> exported from crome export option and saved as .cer file

Comment: below option also doesn't work from me 
var options = {
 url : 'https://example.com',
 ca: [ fs.readFileSync('cp.pem','utf-8') ]
}

Answer (score 1):

As per [the fine manual](https://github.com/request/request#using-optionsagentoptions):

> It is possible to accept other certificates than those signed by
>   generally allowed Certificate Authorities (CAs). This can be useful,
>   for example, when using self-signed certificates. To require a
>   different root certificate, you can specify the signing CA by adding
>   the contents of the CA's certificate file to the agentOptions. The certificate
>   the domain presents must be signed by the root certificate specified:

```
var options = {
  url : 'https://example.com',
  agentOptions: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem')
  }
}
```

Comment: This also seems doesn't work for me... My pem file contains begin followed by a key and then end.

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct certificate? Because a quick PoC works just fine for me: https://gist.github.com/527cfb3d9d731d48733194dc35c205dd

Comment: I'm not sure whether server has same certificate or not like you created in poc. I exported .cer file from chrome browser.

Comment: .cer looks like.  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: If I do the same (save the self-signed certificate from Chrome), it still works for me, so not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine hopefully:

```
  var options = {
      url : 'https://example.com',
      ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem'),
      insecure: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
  }

  console.log(options)

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); 
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
      console.log('body:', body ); 
  });
```

Comment: Could you add any explanations for your code please? :)

Comment: It's just good practice to explain what you've changed and why so that your answer won't just solve the problem, it will help the OP :)

Comment: thing is any web application required certificate so that it can verify the request is coming form the legitimate source but there're some general certificate which are used to verify that in case you are sending the custom certificate what you have to do is that you need to pass in extra parameter which are insecure: true i.e. for even if the certificate is not valid just verify the request and reject unauthorized: false is for so that even it seems like request is unauthorized does not reject it